# Get item at nth index from a collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection

Is there a way to get an item at the nth index from a collection without necessarily loop over all the collection?

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe there is a way to grab a specific index from Varien_Data_Collection (however I would love to be proven wrong on this!)

Notwithstanding, here are my attempts.

```
    /**
     * Method 1,
     * Using LIMIT to grab the 9th item, a new query for each item.
     * Inefficient but fun!
     */
    $collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
    $collection->setPageSize(1);
    $collection->setCurPage(9);
    $ninthItem = $collection->getFirstItem();

    /**
     * Method 2,
     * the collection toArray functionality.
     *
     * It actually iterates through the collection within the toArray call,
     * but at least it saves you from doing the iteration yourself!
     */
    $collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
    $collectionData = $collection->toArray();
    $ninthItem = $collectionData['items'][8];
```

Comment: A side note - steer clear of `getFirstItem()` unless you know the collection is small (or you have limited it to be small) as it loads the entire collection and then pulls the first item from the `_items` array which is pretty inefficient.

Comment: Doesn't pretty much any call to a collection that returns data call load(), which then loads the entire collection into the _items array? 

If so then it isn't really a problem with getFirstItem() and I'd see no better way of getting the first item from a collection.

Comment: Yes anything which accesses the collection loads it (i.e. `foreach` etc) but in the case of `getFirstItem()` you are loading the entire collection but only pulling the first result.  Why pull 1000 rows from the database when you actually only need 1?  In your example it's fine because you have limited the collection but for those who refer to this answer later it's an important point.

Comment: calling toArray method on my Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection all the items are turned into associative array. I need to have Mage_Catalog_Model_Product item instead of the associative array. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @JonathanHussey, Aye I get you now.

Sorry gianis6, not that I know of!

Comment: @gianis6 Your best option really is to have use a limit and offset on the collection - most efficient and you get an object at the end.  Obviously you may need to rethink that if you need more than one result but a few 1 entry collections is still going to be quicker than one large collection.